# ActiveJob::DeserializationError in a after_create callback - Record Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

In a Rails 6 app, I have the following code.

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  after_create     :publish_creation

  def publish_creation
    Publishers::Reservations::CreateJob.perform_later(self)
  end
end

class Publishers::Reservations::CreateJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(reservation)
    puts reservation.inspect #dummy code for testing
  end
end
```

The majority of times I create a `Reservation` (the record is always created in the DB), I get the error below

> 2020-02-14T09:54:03.707Z pid=81787 tid=1xmj WARN:
>   `ActiveJob::DeserializationError: Error while trying to deserialize
>   arguments: Couldn't find Reservation with 'id'= 35651cf7-35bc-4da0-bb0d-6285ac093d22`

The first time Sidekiq retries to process the job, it always finds the `Reservation` and everything works fine.

> `Reservation id: "35651cf7-35bc-4da0-bb0d-6285ac093d22", analysis_id:
>   "6b3b167b-1279-49c0-991a-b580c375fd0f", reservable_type: "User",
>   reservable_id: "94f60c16-29d4-4372-983b-7544c393a7e6",
>   reserved_between: 2020-02-10 08:00:00 UTC..2020-02-10 08:10:00 UTC,
>   state: "scheduled", created_at: "2020-02-14 10:02:28", updated_at:
>   "2020-02-14 10:02:28"`

Am I missing anything here?
Is this something related to the fact I'm running in `development` mode and it should disappear once I move to `production`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `after_commit` instead of `after_create`. This is because

> **after_create** - Is called after Model.save on new objects that haven‘t been saved yet (no record exists). In the case of `after_create`, this will always be before the call to save (or create) returns. Rails wraps every save inside a transaction and the before/after create callbacks run inside that transaction.
>
> **after_commit** - Is called after the database transaction is completed. With `after_commit`, your code doesn't run until after the outermost transaction was committed.

Answer (score 3):

At Rails 5+ you can use `after_create_commit` ([docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#transaction-callbacks))

It will run after the create transaction so the record will already be created, but unlike `after_commit` it will only run after `create`, not after `update` nor `destroy`.

It's an alias for:
`after_commit :your_callback, on: :create`